# Firebase - Missing Api Key

Tags: android, firebase

I'm using Google's Firebase database. I have registered to the Firebase Console and also downloaded the JSON file, but for some reason it gives me that kind of error.

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'.
>    Missing api_key/current_key object

Well I don't know where should I put the api key.

**this is my gradle(module app)**

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
    apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.udacity.firebase.shoppinglistplusplus"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        it.buildConfigField 'String','UNIQUE_FIREBASE_ROOT_URL', UniqueFirebaseRootUrl
    }
    debug {
    }
}

/* This for anyone following along with the repo. Since you will have a different
 * root URL, this code loads up a value from your gradle.properties file.
 */

buildTypes.each {
    it.buildConfigField 'String', 'UNIQUE_FIREBASE_ROOT_URL', UniqueFirebaseRootUrl
}

packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE-FIREBASE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
}

 }

 dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.0.1'

/* Firebase SDK */
compile 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.4.0'

/* Firebase UI */
compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:0.2.2'

/* For Google Play Services */
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-safetynet:9.0.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.0.0'

  }
    apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

**this is gradle(project)**

```
   // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to     
       all sub-projects/modules.

  buildscript {
    repositories {
       jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
      classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.1'
       classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
   }

  allprojects {
     repositories {
      jcenter()
      }
  }
```

---

If something is missing please let me know

Comment: did you place the `google-services.json` in the `app/` directory

Comment: You have duplicate lines in build.gradle. (like `apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'` at the top and bottom). It's better to clean up.

Comment: JoelRaju i did place the google-services.json in thr app/ directory                          Toris i cleaned the duplicate line and still not working, same error

Comment: By adding the following line `"api_key": [{ "current_key": "" }]` in the file `google-services.json`. It resolve my issue

Answer (score 1):

you should place the `google-services.json` in the `app/` directory

see docs: https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup#add_firebase_to_your_app

Answer (score 1):

Well thanks guys, i deleted the Jsonfile and download again. Probably i had problem with that file. now its fixed!

Answer (score 0):

Another option is set this default value to api_key atribute  on google-services.json

"api_key": [{"current_key": XXX }],

Answer (score 0):

Recently had same problem and i checked the google-services.json file which i pasted into the project. There wasn't any key at api key line:
"api_key": [],
Download json file again and get key from new one