# How to manually generates google-services.json

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, firebase-authentication, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am trying to add `google-services.json` to the project. in Android studio, i navigated to 'project' view and i added 'google-services.json' to 'app' directory.
Then, I opened 'google-services.json' file and the only change i t did to it, is adding the project's package name in 'package_name' attribute in 'client' object as shown in `google-services.json`.

And according to link-1 below, it says:

```
The main result of the JSON processing is to produce two XML files which you can reference as Android resources in your Java code... in

app/build/generated/res/google-services/{build_type}/values/values.xml

AND.

app/build/generated/res/google-services/{flavor}/{build_type}/xml/global_tracker.xml
```

but in my case, i got only one .xml file as shown in `image-1` below. However, as stated in `link-1`, one can generates these files manually by creating a .xml file.

I referred to `link-1` to know the required values -please have a look at `image-2`-I tried to generate it but I could not find the values marked with `??????`. please have a look at `missing-values-file` below.

1- please let me know how to find these missing values marked with `???????` in `missing-values-file`?

2- what is the purpose of `server API key` and `Sender id` generated by `GCM`? why they are not used in the file posted in the section `missing-values-file`

**link-1: [here](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/google-services-plugin#adding_the_json_file)**.

**link-2: the configuration file was downloaded from [here](https://developers.google.com/mobile/add?platform=android&cntapi=signin&cntapp=Default%20Demo%20App&cntpkg=com.google.samples.quickstart.signin&cnturl=https:%2F%2Fdevelopers.google.com%2Fidentity%2Fsign-in%2Fandroid%2Fstart%3Fconfigured%3Dtrue&cntlbl=Continue%20with%20Try%20Sign-Inx) **

**google-services.json**:
the values that contain 'x' are actually existing but i removed them for security

```
{
"project_info": {
"project_number": "119xxx",
"project_id": "defxxx"
},
"client": [
{
  "client_info": {
    "mobilesdk_app_id": "1:1xxx",
    "android_client_info": {
      "package_name": "eu.xxx"
    }
  },
  "oauth_client": [
    {
      "client_id": "119xxx",
      "client_type": 3
    }
  ],
  "api_key": [
    {
      "current_key": "AIzxxx"
    }
  ],
  "services": {
    "analytics_service": {
      "status": 1
    },
    "appinvite_service": {
      "status": 1,
      "other_platform_oauth_client": []
    },
    "ads_service": {
      "status": 1
    }
  }
}
],
"configuration_version": "1"
}
```

**image-1**:

[image]

**missing-values-file**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

<! -- Present in all applications -->
<string name="google_app_id" translatable="false">1:1xxx</string>

<! -- Present in applications with the appropriate services configured -->
<string name="gcm_defaultSenderId" translatable="false">119xxx</string>
<string name="default_web_client_id" translatable="false">119xxxx</string>
<string name="ga_trackingId" translatable="false">??????</string>
<string name="firebase_database_url" translatable="false">???????</string>
<string name="google_api_key" translatable="false">???????</string>
<string name="google_crash_reporting_api_key" translatable="false">???????</string>

</resources>
```

**image-2**

The required values

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To generate a configuration file and credentials for your project, follow the steps given in [creating an API project](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/client#create-an-api-project)

Then, [add the configuration file to your project](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/client#add-the-configuration-file-to-your-project).

> The Google Services plugin for Gradle parses configuration information from the `google-services.json` file. Add the plugin to your project by updating your top-level `build.gradle` and your app-level `build.gradle` files as follows:
>
> 1. Add the dependency to your **project-level `build.gradle`**:
>
>    `classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'`
> 2. Add the plugin to your **app-level `build.gradle`**:
>
>    `apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'`

See this related [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40270202/firebase-missing-api-key) for additional insights. And this [thread](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35353628) might also help.